# PNG encoded with multiple images + HTML usage

Tags: html, png, css-sprites

I got a PNG having multiple images encoded in it. How do I make use of all the images in a HTML, one for default, on mouse over use the other (I don't want to create different images and work).

Are there any examples?

Comment: What do you mean by encoded? Encoded as in, put underneath or next to each other? Or encoded like in a multi-page TIFF (If that's possible in PNG)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean you have a bunch saved together in one big image, check out [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

If you mean something else, good luck. Try reworking them into sprites. :D

Answer (score 4):

[Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/)!